# How to search if a substring is into a binary file in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I'm tyring to get one piece of information out of a PDF file. If I display the PDF file in a text editor, I always find what I'm looking for in the form

```
/Contents (Localidad: XXXXXXXXXXX)
```

The X's are the things I want.

I know there is PyPDF2 to read PDF files, problem is, I don't find this piece using it. I can read the rest of the file, and convert it to text and so on, but I can't get this specific piece of information using PyPDF2.

So, I thought I could do something like:

```
file = open("yada.pdf", "rb")
for line in file:
    if "(Localidad:" in line:
        # Extract the XXX's
```

Of course if I do it this way, Python will complain about it: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

What do you think? I'm completely wrong doing it this way? What would be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import re
with open("yada.pdf", "rb") as f:
    text = str(f.read()) # This will return the contents of the pdf in string format
    location = re.findall("/Contents \(Localidad: (.+?)\)", text)
    f.close()
```